# Event handlers for all types of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to provide a function which will listen for all button click events.

The web developer may use different kinds of buttons..

```
<button></button>
```

or

```
<input type="button"></input>
```

or

```
<div class="button"></div>
```

etc.

Is there a way to add a common event handler for all of these different kind of buttons? I would like to avoid manually writing event handlers for every possible way of creating a button.

**EDIT:**
Many of you have posted a nice solution of creating a common class but unfortunately i am not the one creating the buttons i am providing a function, which the app/site developer will call and i will collect all types of button click events and send them to a server.

Comment: Define a global `btn-click` class to the tags you want to add the click event on

Comment: _This response is after your edit_. If you don't use a `div` as a `button` then it is possible. But you need something to identify that, that particular `div` is acting as a button.

Comment: maybe i can hard code the div part, but how about other ways of creating buttons, there must be more than the 3 ways i mentioned right?

Comment: In HTML almost all elements has an attached `onclick` event with it. So unless you _IDENTIFY_ which all elements should act as a button, there is no generic way.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to add a `common class` to all those `elements`:

```
 <buttonclass="btn"></button>
   <input type="button" class="btn"></input>
   <div class="button btn"></div>
```

Then listen on those elements with the help of that class:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
 //Your code
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':button, .button').on('click', function() {
    // Event handler code
});
```

I'd recommend you should use the common class to all type of buttons and add event using class:

```
<button class="myButton"></button>
<input type="button" class="myButton"></input>
<div class="button"></div>


$('.myButton').on('click', function() {
    // Event handler code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you created your click event handler like for example:

```
$('.btn-click').click(function() {
    alert('Hello World');
});
```

Then you can add this event to several different tags just by defining the `btn-click` class to it.

```
<button class="btn-click"></button>

<input type="button" class="btn-click"></input>

<div class="button btn-click"></div>
```

Working JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/gvjLLf9L/

Comment: It's a nice technique but, the thing is i am not the one creating the button i'm just providing an sdk/api whatever to collect generic events and send them to a server.

Comment: And you can't give this information to the other people that are creating the buttons that they have to append the `btn-click` class in order to append an onclick event?

Comment: I dunnow, i can include that in the documentation i think, but when the app/site developers use my function they most likely would  have done pretty much everything else.